# using demorgan law to change function to inv-nand

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, discrete-mathematics, digital-design, boolean-algebra

we have :

```
F  =  A C'D' + B'C'
```

Use De’Morgan’s law to convert the NOT-AND-OR function to NOT-NAND 
function (with minimum number of gates). Show the conversion steps. Keep in 
mind that you have only NAND gates with fan-in = 2.

i did this but i feel its wrong

```
    (AC’).D’+B’C’
= (( (AC’).D’+  B’C’ )’)’ using involution law
= (   ((AC’).D’)’. (B’C’)’  )’
```

the question is really wierd i can draw it but i cant understand how to do it using demorgan

Comment: feelings don't count in logic; construct the truth table of each to convince yourself

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with it you used the involution law and then you used Demorgan's law in line 3 ,changing the OR into NAND

Involution Law:  (p')'=p

demorgan law 1 : (A.B)' = A'+B'

```
            {NAND} = {Negative OR}
```

demorgan law 2:(A+B)'=A'.B'

```
           {NOR} ={Negative AND}
```